# Numpad not giving numbers in fromCharCode

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, angularjs-directive

I'd like to only allow certain keypresses in my inputfields.

Problem is that numpads values in `String.fromCharCode` doesn't correspond to the real chars...

Also side note, my chrome translates commas (`String.fromCharCode(188)`) into "¼" - though it should be a "," ?

I've done it like this:

**Javascript directive:**

```
angular.module('LTS').directive('allowed', function () {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        link: function (scope, element, attrs, modelCtrl) {
            var allowedLowerCaseLetters = attrs.allowed.toLowerCase();
            element.on('keydown', function (event) {
                var pressedChar = String.fromCharCode(event.keyCode).toLowerCase();
                if (event.keyCode === 188) {
                    pressedChar = ",";
                }
                if (allowedLowerCaseLetters.indexOf(pressedChar) > -1 || event.keyCode === 8 || event.keyCode === 37 || event.keyCode === 39) {
//                    console.log(pressedChar+" should be added to model.");
                } else {
                    //TODO maybe add a notification ?
                    event.preventDefault();
                }
            });
        }
    };
});
```

**HTML:**

```
<input id="invoiceAmount" class="form-control importInput" type="text" ng-model="import.invoiceAmount"  allowed="1234567890,">
```

**Beware**
Firefox has it's code in "event.charCode" instead of keyCode on keypress

Comment: why do you say `String.fromCharCode(188)` should return `,`? Comma ASCII/Unicode is 44.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`String.fromCharCode`](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/fromCharCode) and [`event.keyCode`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/KeyboardEvent/keyCode) are different.

`String.fromCharCode` expect Unicode codes as parameters and then return the character associated to them.

`event.keyCode` **in keydown events** implementation is a bit confusing, they return the code of the key being pressed and not of the character printed. However using it in keypress events will return the expected values and the correct ones to be used in `String.fromCharCode`.

```js
 function f(e){
  document.querySelector('div').innerHTML += e.type + ' - ' + e.keyCode + ' - ' + String.fromCharCode(e.keyCode) + '<br/>';
  }

document.querySelector('input').addEventListener('keydown', f);
document.querySelector('input').addEventListener('keypress', f);
```

```html
<input />
<div></div>
```